# Why is the glob method finding different files in Python?

Tags: python, path, pycharm, find, glob

If I search for all the directories via my python file app.py, the terminal does not retrieve  the same files/directories as it does if I searched for them in a different python file.  If I insert the same code into another python file titled MessingAround.py to find the documents, different titles show up in the terminal. Shouldn't I come up with the same results, since the files are both in the same location? I have attached the images to this question.

As you can see, the results in the terminal are different. Why is that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the working directory specified in the two run configurations are different, or that the unsorted glob looks different each time it is run.

Regardless, being specific about the path you want to glob (and sorting the glob) should resolve the problem:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(__file__).parent  # The directory that this file is in

for file in sorted(path.glob('*')):
    print(file)
```

Comment: thanks, you were right, the directories were indeed different - went to edit the app.py file and it showed a blank in the "working directory" section. I copy/pasted same directory as the one MessingAround.py is in, and it seems to work!